# Microsoft Graph Webhooks - Subscribe to User Group Membership

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

My question is basically the same as this one, except I want to subscribe to the user's group changes rather than calendar: [Microsoft Graph webhooks - subscribe to user calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53248440/microsoft-graph-webhooks-subscribe-to-user-calendars)

The overall idea is that when a user is removed from (or added to) a group, then the subscription listener would be notified.

What `resource` and `changeType` would I specify?

Answer (score 1):

To get notified when a user is removed or added to the group, you should check the group resource and the changeType should be updated, your request should look like this:

```
 {
   "changeType": "updated",
   "notificationUrl": "{notification-url}",
   "resource": "groups/{group-id}",
   "expirationDateTime":"2021-11-20T18:23:45.9356913Z",
   "clientState": "secretClientValue",
   "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
}
```

Let me know whether this helps and if you have further questions.